# Why circling around blackhole slows the time? In easy language

Tags: black-holes, time

I have read theories and articles about it but didn't get much(not a scientist though).

Can somebody explain to me, most possibly in easy language and terminology that why a person's time will slow down if he rotates around a blackhole, as compare to the person present on earth?

Thanks before for help and explanation. :-)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with black holes.   You are asking about the effects of gravity, and those effects are qualitatively the same near a black hole as they are near any massive object.

Comment: This question has been posted previously [on Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/92919/29), where it was put on hold as off topic for being about the real world with no imaginary component.